# Check box won't append

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

So the HTML has these elements, there can be a random number of them. I would simply like to create a check box, and add it to each element with the class name "username".

So when a new element with the class "username" gets created or when the page is opened. It'll add a check box to it.

Here's my script.

```
var chec = document.createElement("div");     //Creates the div..
chec.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" value="test">'; //Create checkbox

var addc = document.querySelector("span[class='username']") // username Element.

var i;
for (i = 0; i < addc.length; i++) {
chec += addc[i];
}
```

It doesn't add the check boxes. Can someone help me understand why and possibly help me with my script.

Comment: what error are you getting? is addc an array?

Comment: This is not how you add element, You need `addc.appenChild(chec)` and you need to create element in loop.

Comment: I don't that's correct. The HTML has these elements, there can be a random number of them. I would simply like to create a check box, and add it to each element with the class name "username".

Comment: *"can be created dynamically..."* do you have access to the function that dynamically creates these elements ? @愛雨iⱣines

Comment: You can't create one element and add it to multiple places you need multiple elements, also `check += addc[i]` make no sens you're adding DOM node to DOM node it will create string `"[Object object][Object object]..."`

Comment: I'm just trying to get some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var addc = document.querySelectorAll("span.username") // Get all elements with class "username"

for (var i = 0; i < addc.length; i++) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  var check = document.createElement("input");
  check.type = "checkbox";
  check.value = "test";
  div.appendChild(check);
  addc[i].appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<span class="username"></span>

<span class="username"></span>

<span class="username"></span>
```

Comment: why not just `span.username` instead of `span[class='username']` ? Also, an `inline` level element, like the `span` here, can't have `block` level elements as its children.

Comment: Right. Edited my answer